# Right click context menu in Windows 10 is completely blank

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

I have Windows 10 Pro build 16299.492 completely up to date on a computer with an AMD FX 8350 CPU, 16 GB DDR3 RAM, an Asus M5A99X EVO R2.0 and an Nvidia Geforce GTX 1070 GPU (PNY Founders Edition). Every now and then, when I right click in the Windows Explorer, all my right click menu items suddenly disappear. Searching online has turned up two long, extensive threads at Microsoft's official tech support site [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-right-click-menu-text-disappear/2edbcc13-eb5c-433e-a77c-3c96ce1da0d4) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/right-click-menu-context-menu-contains-blank-lines/b5191eae-c7f6-4813-afa7-7bf4645a5547?page=1), where many other users report the same issue and with several Microsoft tech support representatives unsuccessfully trying to fix this issue.

Does anyone here have any idea of how to fix this?

(Please note: the folder items do not go missing, they have been removed for privacy but they display fine on my computer).

[image: Right click menu items missing]

Comment: Have you restarted the PC?

Comment: Usually, a problem with the context menu indicates that some application has flubbed its attempt to register it's own context menu extensions. Is there any pattern to what you right-clicked on (files, folders, a specific file type, the desktop, etc) when the context menu malfunctions? What about when right-clicking in a browser window?

Comment: 16299.492 is approximately 2 weeks old.  I am not even including the fact, 1709, is no longer the current release branch.

Comment: My system could have missed a recent update. I kinda have the suspicion that running VMware Player can block updates from being installed, since I always run a VM and I have almost never seen the pending restart window. I'm going to do that once I get home.

Comment: Also, this error goes away when I restart the computer but then it happens again. From what I gathered, sometimes it happens after a few hours, sometimes after just a few minutes.

Comment: After my last post I made sure to have Windows Update look for updates, and sure enough, I did miss one or two updates. I installed them and rebooted my system. However, I am still getting the blank right click menu.

Comment: I still haven't been able to pinpoint any event causing it: the last time it began, I was playing videogames during the night, and during that time the context menu displayed properly. Then I went to sleep, and when I returned to my computer the next day, the context menu was blank again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple weeks after the question was posted, my system received an update to Version 1803 Build 17134.165. Since this update was installed, I haven't experienced this issue anymore.

I believe we can call it quits on this issue, and that the fix is to wait for the update to this build of Windows 10 to roll out for your system and geography.

[image: Windows build that fixes the issue]